# Не выводиться диалоговое окно

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. При запуске кода через VSCode не появляется диалоговое окно

```js
prompt('Сколько фильмов вы уже посмотрели?', '')
alert("Alert")
```

код тут не имеет значения как я понимаю, что-то скорее всего в настройках но понять бы что

Answer (score 1):

В VSCode такие функции работать не будут.

Вам нужно запускать это в браузере, так как это часть браузера.
В настройках в VSCode ничего нельзя поменять, чтобы это заработало.

Comment: Извините, но длиннее ответ я не придумал.